# Button component does not receive DataTable props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I am trying to add a button to my vuejs DataTable. I created a Button component and I can add it as a column in my DataTable, but I can't send it through props. I do not have full knowledge of vue, for sure I am doing something wrong.

```
  Vue.component('edit-button', {
        template: `
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" @click="goToUpdatePage">Edit</button>
    `,
        props: ['data'],
        methods: {
            goToUpdatePage: function(){
                alert(data)
            }
        }
    });

    export default {


        data() {
            return {
                numeroPagina: 1,

                tiposNatureza: [],
                utisMoveis: [],
                list: [],

                filtros: {
                    dataInicial: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
                    dataFinal: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
                    selectedUtisMoveis: [],
                    selectedStatus: [],
                    selectedTipoNatureza: [],
                    selectedTipoPesquisa: ''
                },

                tabela: {
                    columns: [
                        {

                            // <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado">${row.DESCRICAO}</a>
                            label: 'Descrição', representedAs: function (row) {
                                if (row.DESCRICAO) return `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado">${row.DESCRICAO}</a> <button onclick="alertMe('TESTE')">TESTE</button>`
                                else return '<b>Sem informação</b>'
                            }, interpolate: true
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Quantidade', representedAs: function (row) {
                                return `<p><span class="label label-primary" style="font-size: 17px">${row.QTD}</span></p>`
                            }, interpolate: true
                        },

                        {

                            label: 'Action',
                            component: 'edit-button',
                            data: 'row',
                            component_data: {
                                path: 'contact',
                                action: 'update'
                            }
                        }

                    ],
                    rows: []
                }

            }
        }
```

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h2 v-if="quantidadeDeRegistros > 0">Foram encontrado(s) {{ quantidadeDeRegistros }}
                            resultado(s)</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content no-padding" style="font-size: 15px">
                        <datatable :columns="tabela.columns" :data="tabela.rows"></datatable>
                        <datatable-pager v-model="numeroPagina" type="abbreviated" :per-page="8"></datatable-pager>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need to create a button that takes the information from the selected row (row.DESCRIPTION) and sends it to a method, where I will do some dealing in a modal. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi Luccaz, Welcome to stackoverflow community. In order to get the help I suggest you to translate your language to Stackoverflow platform language ("English").

Comment: Just translated and edited his question, if the OP accepted the edit we can have the english written question

Comment: When you access your props in component you need to use this keyword. So when you access it inside method you use: this.data. Also it would be helpful if you share with us console log error so we can easily focus on what could be error in your code.

Comment: the alert returns me undefined.

    Vue.component('edit-button', {
        template: `
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" @click="goToUpdatePage">Edit</button>
 `,
        props: ['data'],
        methods: {
            goToUpdatePage: function(){
                alert(this.data)
            }
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this` to reference the component scope.

```
alert(this.data)
```

And remove:

```
props: ['data'],
```

You do not want a passed in prop called `data`.  You want the component's defined data `property`